# How to get accuracy of each class in Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: python, class, tensorflow, evaluate

I'm using Estimator in Python3 based on Premade Estimator from example

> (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/premade_estimators).

I normally train the network and then evaluate.
As the result of *classifier.evaluate(...)* I get python dictionary, e.g.:

```
eval_result = {'loss': 14.673522, 'average_loss': 0.1470208, 'accuracy': 0.9460823, 'global_step': 1000}
```

But **how** can I **get** the **accuracy of each output class** from classifier? I need accuracy array e.g. like: `class = [0.924012,0.89478,0.945123,0.685042]`

Comment: In a canned estimator, like [`DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier), the metrics are fixed and cannot be changed within the estimator (e.g. see `_MultiClassHeadWithSoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss`, method `_eval_metric_ops` in [`tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py)). You can either make your own [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) from scratch or simply compute it yourself from the result of `predict`.